# crear politicas para las url no tengan expiración en aws s3

Tags: aws, cloud

estoy subiendo videos a aws s3 desde mi backend y guardo las urls generadas en una base de datos, pero las url expiran después de dos días y necesito que las url expiren. estoy intentando agregar políticas de acceso al bucken en la sección de permisos, pero me sale error de api
esta es la políticas que intento agregar.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1677375651726",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllAccess",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuckettest",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "s3"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las únicas URLs que deberían caducar son las presigned.

Si dejas el bucket con acceso a Internet, las URL deberían tener una URL del tipo

- https://bucket-name.s3.region-code.amazonaws.com/key-name

o

- https://s3.region-code.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key-name

Estas URLs no tienen ninguna marca de tiempo, por lo que no caducan mientras el bucket esté expuesto a Internet ... ahora, recuerda que en estos casos pagarás por cada acceso a uno de estos archivos

Más información: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html

Por otro lado, la caducidad de los enlaces no depende de las políticas IAM, ya que éstas no tienen acceso a marcas de tiempo

Comment: https://codeshare.io/MNEZKJ esa es la función que cree para subir videos a s3. y me genera un link de este tipo:
https://bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/video-1677381262853. . .
seguido de las querys, pero los links caducan

Comment: @AngelVera `const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, getCommand)` ahí estás consiguiendo una *presigned* url, que son, como te he dicho, las únicas que caducan. Sigue este [enlace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-block-public-access-bucket.html) para que tu bucket pueda ser accedido desde Internet y no necesites usar las presigned para acceder a las imágenes